# Bootstrap inside Wordpress post

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I created [this testpage](http://www.neuromind.cc/beta/cdss_test.html) with Bootstrap which is working perfectly. When resizing to smartphone format, the result block (visible when all radio buttons are entered) is correctly aligned BELOW the other container. On a normal screen, it is displayed next to it.

Now, when I insert the same code [inside a Wordpress post](http://www.neuromind.cc/news/form-javascript-test/) the realignment for mobile phone does not work anymore. I have been hacking the theme and looking at the generated html source code of the page, but I cannot understand why it is not working correctly. It has to be something inside the header of the page, but what is not clear to me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to reproduce the same structure. On the example .container is just below the  <body> tag. You have absolute position in parents id such as #main and #menu-content.

Try to make it works just like the example and then add your proper structure element by element to see what's wrong :)

Comment: Can't mark your comment as solution, but actually it was. I did not think of the possibility to grab the generated html from the PHP and start messing around with that. It turned out to be the theme's CSS file and from those 12,000 lines, the section that used the .row class (as Bootstrap also uses rows for layout). Commented that part out and now it works as it should!

Comment: Glad my comment helped :)